# bash - reading multiple input files and creating matching output files by name and sequence

Tags: bash, scripting

I do not know much bash scripting, but I know the task I would like to do would be greatly simplified by it. I would like to test a program against expected output using many test input files.

For example, I have files named "input1.txt, input2.txt, input3.text..." and expected output in files "output1.txt, output2.txt, output3.txt...".  I would like to run my program with each of the input files and output a corresponding "test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt...".  Then I would do a "cmp output1.txt test1.txt" for each file.

So I think it would start like this.. roughly..

```
for i in input*;
do
    ./myprog.py < "$i" > someoutputthing;
done
```

One question I have is: how would I match the numbers in the filename? Thanks for your help.

Comment: ask @anubhava ... he can answer

Comment: @MortezaLSC: I believe OP accepted the answer below as it worked well for the problem posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input file name pattern is `inputX.txt`, you need to remove `input` from the beginning. You do not have to remove the extension, as you want to use the same for output:

```
output=output${i#input}
```

See Parameter Expansion in `man bash`.